# What is the max possible value of magnitude in polar system in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, polar-coordinates

In OpenCV I'm using cartToPolar function and I want to know the max possible value of calculated magnitude. Can it be greater than 255? I found something about calculation in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) about Hough Line Transform, but I still do not know the max value. I need this to calculate histograms, to devide the ranges for right buckets.

Best regards,

Comment: The [`cartToPolar()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=carttopolar#carttopolar) function is used for transforming *points*, not an image. You input `x,y` pairs and get returned `rho, theta` pairs. The *magnitude* can be arbitrarily large, because you can input arbitrarily large inputs `x,y`. You definitely should not be using `cartToPolar()` to calculate histograms. Post your attempted solution at creating histograms, and perhaps open a new question that adequately describes the *overall goal* you want to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I will do like you said. Thank you for your answer.